# Using multiple server databases

Tags: mysql, php

I was just seeking some higher advice on whether or not having your main data on one database, then having separate server database to use for frequent updating and reading will prove to be an optimization or a failure. My logic was that sharing the load like this across 2 separate server databases will be quicker than packing it all in on one shared hosting Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your "main data"...?

Comment: Being the bulk of what I need to store, such as the member details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can and should use multiple servers if you have a high load in your mysql.

you need to see what solution works to you:

- Replication

  - Master -> Slave: 
    In this one, you will write(and also will be able to read) in the master server, and read from slave,
  - Master -> Master: In this one, you will be able to write and read in both servers (they will be action as master and slave), you need to be careful with AUTO_INCREMENTS
- Cluster: You can have a look on mysql cluster, I'll recommend this option if you have more than 4 server (masters or slaves in total).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and right away I can see why I would have to be careful with AUTO_INCREMENTS with the Master->Master method. Thanks for the tips.